# Recommendations to run a Java SE container application on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Java SE application which is nothing but a Kafka consumer. It is not exposing any REST endpoint but it polls data from Kafka topic and pushes to Elastic Search. This SE application is docker containerized and we need to run this to Kubernetes.

1. What are the recommendations for running java SE application on Kubernetes?
2. Any sample deployment yaml file for this requirement?

Comment: Does it consume from a Kafka topic that has multiple partitions?

Comment: yes, it will. We are considering to have one Kafka consumer pod will deal with one partition and there can be multiple pods in a given consumer group.

Answer (score 0):

Some recommendations based on own experience, at my company all of our stuff is java and kafka based.

`Java`
1. You don't need a kubernetes service (obviously since you don't expose a server). 
2. Set `Heap Size` limits by making sure the container can read an environment variable for `XMS` and `XMS`. 
3. Set `spec.resources.limits.[]` and `spec.resources.requests.[]` to values above XMX and XMS. Your container might need some extra resources for other operations. 
`Kafka`
4. Make sure to have a static `consumer group`. So if you scale your application, it does not produce rebalances.
5. Create a variable to configure number of consumers per consumergroup. You can tune `throughput` with it.

Comment: 1. You don't need a Kubernetes service (obviously since you don't expose a server).
Does this mean that it is not recommended to run a java SE application on k8s? If all applications on k8s and only a SE application need to deploy outside of the k8s cluster? We need to get this SE piece also in k8s.

Comment: No, it means you don't need k8s service object since you don't need to load balance the deployment. Of course it can be run on kubernetes.